# Swift array declaration

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift-playground

I want to declare an array in a Swift Playground, but doing it this way

```
var lengths: [Int] = []
```

produces a `Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'` error. However, declaring the array this other way, works perfectly

```
var lengths: Int[] = []
```

I'm running Xcode 6-beta build version 6A215l.

Comment: Update to Xcode 6 beta 4! The array syntax changed in beta 4.

Comment: @MartinR It was beta 3.

Comment: Yes, it was in beta 3: http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_4_o2p8fz/xcode_6_beta_4_release_notes.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of Arrays was changed in Beta 3. Your first line gives me that error in the first beta. If you upgrade to the newest beta it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are running a beta version of Xcode that is over a month old. Download the newest version.